# Stop User From Publishing an Event if the Start Date is Before a Certain Month Using Rules

Tags: rules, datetime

I'm working on a development site that will not be launching for a few months. I'm looking to create a rule that will not allow a user to publish an event if the event's start date is prior to launch. I am using the date field in this content type.

How could I accomplish this with rules? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that Rules is required to do that.

I would rather use [Field Validation module](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation). It is able to configure complex validation rules for any field.

In its submodule called "Field validation extras" there's a validation rule that will help you, it's called "Date range2". You can set a specific minimum date according to your needs, and a far enough maximum date.

Comment: Thanks ermannob! I was actually able to configure a rule to do this, but you're solution seems a lot more simple.